# Slack API: How to authenticate with oAuth?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, oauth, slack-api

I'm following [Slack's docs on authenticating with oAuth.](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#authenticating-oauth)

The scopes and the tokens are well set up. I'm struggling setting up the `installationStore.`

This is the code I'm using to fetch data from my Firestore DB:

```
  installationStore: {
    fetchInstallation: async InstallQuery => {
      // change the line below so it fetches from your database
      // return await database.get(InstallQuery.teamId);

  let cityRef = db.collection("teams").doc(InstallQuery.teamId);
  let getDoc = cityRef
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log("No such document!");
      } else {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting document", err);
    });

  return await getDoc;
}
}
```

I am not sure if what I should return-await is getDoc, or not. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
installationStore: {
  fetchInstallation: async (InstallQuery) => {
    return await getData();
  };
}

async function getData() {
  try {
    let cityRef = db.collection("teams").doc(InstallQuery.teamId);
    let doc = await cityRef.get();
    return doc.data();
  } catch(ex){
      throw new Error("Failed fetching installation");
    }
}
```